# Which XPath to use while scraping Google Play store?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-play, web-crawler, scrapy

I am scraping the Google Play store for the app reviews. I am able to get only 40 reviews only. The problem is in the xhr path upon reaching scrapy throws error:

```
Http status code not handled or not allowed
```

Code:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
    
    
class Product(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    
    
class aqaqspider(BaseSpider):
    name = "gaana"
    allowed_domains = ["play.google.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gaana&hl=en",
    ]
    page = 1
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//div[@class="single-review"]')
    
        if not products:
            raise CloseSpider("No more products!")
    
        for product in products:
            item = Product()
            #item['brand'] = product.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'qa-brandName')]/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            item['title'] = product.xpath('.//.//div/div/span[@class="author-name"]/a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            yield item
    
        self.page += 1
        yield Request(url="https://play.google.com/store/getreviews?authuser=1" ,
                      headers={"Referer": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gaana&hl=en", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
                      callback=self.parse, 
                      dont_filter=True)
```

Please don't say that it is against their Terms of Use. I know that but I need to learn things and move on. I am not exploiting anything.

Comment: looks like the following request contains a json format, so you need to parse it first.

Comment: @eLRuLL can you help me on that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html , `json.loads(response.text)`